# param is missing or the value is empty: comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've been stuck on this for awhile with no luck. Essentially I'm trying to create a "Reply button" that generates an inline form a user can fill out to respond to a comment. I used straight up javascript to generate the html when the button is clicked (which I'm aware is probably not the best way to do things, but I couldn't find a better way). Since js doesn't seem to be allowing me to use form helpers I'm not sure how to make everything function correctly.

I'd appreciate some help, or if someone could point me in a direction of a more standard way to accomplish this.

**Error**

```
param is missing or the value is empty: comment
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/comments" class="new_comment" id="new_comment" method="post"> 
<textarea id="content" name = :comment[content] type = "text" cols= "40" rows = "5" /></textarea> 
<input type="submit" value="Reply"> </form>
```

**Controller**

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.save
  redirect_to root_path
end

private
## Strong Parameters 
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "content"
end
```

**Request**

```
Request

Parameters:

{":comment"=>{"content"=>"hey"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was being an idiot, I was able to just go to a traditional rails form designed with helpers and then view the html that was generated to create a properly functioning form.

Here is what I changed to html to so I could get it functioning properly and submitting the required parameters.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /> 
  <textarea name="comment[content]" id="comment_content"> 
  </textarea> <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Reply" /> 
</form>
```